# plot a sequence of numbers with different colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

I have a random list of 0 and 1 with a length > 300. I would like to plot the list with 1 as green and 0 as red as shown in the below pic. What is the best way to do this in matplotlib?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [matplotlib table](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.table.html):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [0,1,0,1,1,0]  # Setup data list
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(len(data)*0.5, 0.5))  # Setup figure
ax.axis("off")  # Just want table, no actual plot

# Create table, with our data array as the single row, and consuming the whole figure space
t = ax.table(cellText=[data], loc="center", cellLoc="center", bbox=[0,0,1,1])

# Iterate over cells to colour them based on value
for idx, cell in t.get_celld().items():
    if data[idx[1]] == 1:
        c = 'g'
    else:
        c = 'r'
    cell.set_edgecolor(c)
    cell.set_facecolor(c)

fig.show()
```